# How is `ls` work compare `*`?

Tags: bash, terminal, ls, du

The result of `ls` is difference between `*`?
For example:
`ls | du -sh` 
will only show one line for total size of current dir.
`du -sh *` 
will show the size of each file or subDir in current dir.

why the result is not same?

Comment: Note! `ls` won't display directory with dot for e.g: "`path/.config`"

Comment: @Noproblem `*` won't expand to include files that start with `.` either unless you `shopt -s dotglob`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls | du -sh` only reports the size of `.` because `du` does not support reading directory names from standard input.
So, executing `ls | du -sh` wastes the `ls` and gives the same result as only running `du -sh`.

Answer (score 1):

`du -sh` doesn't read from stdin. So `whatever | du -sh` is the same as `du -sh`.

`du -sh *` however is expanded to `du -sh file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt` where file1.txt, ... are files / directories in current directory.

When multiply files are specified for `du -sh` the output will display sum for each file, while `du -sh` will only show sum for current directory.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider something like `du $(ls)` to actually pass the output of `ls` to `du` as parameters.  But this is probably not a good idea because file names can be ugly as hell (contain spaces, even newline characters, etc.) and `du` will be only confused by this.

Consider combining `find` and `du` instead.